# pythonで複数のcsvファイルから特定の列を抽出して結合させたい

Tags: python, pandas, csv

やりたいこと：

1. 添付画像のようなcsvファイルが複数ある
2. 各ファイルからプロファイル１の列のデータを抽出
3. 列方向にデータを結合
4. csvファイルとして保存

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
import csv
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

df_dir = './sample1'
df_file = '*.csv'

if __name__ == "__main__":
   for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(df_dir, df_file)):
       with open(f) as file:
           df = pd.read_csv(file, header=2,usecols=[1])
       df_tp = df.transpose()
       with open('./transpose.csv','a') as g:
           writer = csv.writer(g, lineterminator='\n')
           writer.writerows(df_tp)
```

こんな感じで書いていますが、

```
Error: iterable expected, not int
```

というエラーが出てしまいます。
df_tpの中身を見てみると、プロファイル１の数値だけでなくデータ番号(画像のNo.ではなく抽出後のナンバリング(？))も含まれてしまっているのが原因な気がしますがその取り除き方がわかりません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

わかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示願います。

Comment: `iterable expected` と表示されていますので、`writer.writerows(df_tp.itertuples())` としてみてはどうでしょうか。また、`df = pd.read_csv(file, header=2,usecols=[1])` とされていますが、これは `header=1` ではないでしょうか。

Comment: ```writer.writerows(df_tp.itertuples())```にしたらできました！！ありがとうございます！headerに関しては説明が足りていなかったのですがプロファイル１というのもいらず数値だけほしかったので```header=2```で大丈夫でした

Answer (score 2, accepted):

既にコメントにて解決しているようですが、もう一つ別の方法として、元のcsvから1つの列だけ取り出すなら`pandas`やDataFrame操作が不要になる以下のやり方が取れるでしょう。
変更部分にコメントを付けています。

```
import csv
import glob
import os

df_dir = './sample1'
df_file = '*.csv'

if __name__ == "__main__":
   for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(df_dir, df_file)):
      with open(f) as file:
         reader = csv.reader(file)  # pandas ではなく csv を使う
         next(reader)  # 不要な行をスキップ
         next(reader)
         valuelist = [row[1] for row in reader]  # リスト内包表記で指定の列を抽出
      with open('./transpose.csv','a') as g:
          writer = csv.writer(g, lineterminator='\n')
          writer.writerow(valuelist)  # writerows を writerow に変更
```

Comment: なるほど！pandas使わなくてもできるんですね！ありがとうございます。